# Why 'have many in common' is incorrect?

Tags: grammar

Always, we use **'have much in common'**, not **'have many** in common'.

However, I can't find the reason why **'have many in common'** is wrong. This is because I think **'many'** can also be **'pronoun**' like **'much**' is '**pronoun'**. Is this just English usage? I mean there is no exact reason why we do not use **'have many in common'.**

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: For your specific example, "We have a lot in common." is so commonly used I wouldn't change it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it can be correct.

*Much* means *a lot*, an undefined large quantity. You don't have to specifcy much of _what _ you have, but when you do, you use an uncountable concept:

> I don't have much money.
>   He doesn't like it very much.

*Many* means *a lot of items*. Whenever you use *many*, you have to specifiy many *what* you mean, and it has to be a *countable* noun:

> I have many apples.
>   There are many apples, but I don't have many.

In the last example, *many* means *many apples* - it was mentioned just before!

So you could say:

> There are many different reasons to go on holiday, but we don't have many (*reasons*) in common.